# React app deployed on Heroku not recognizing my app.get functions

Tags: reactjs, heroku

Thanks for checking out my post. I am a newer coder who has hit a blocker that I am really struggling to get past! I created a react app which is meant for a bar to digitize their menu and allow for customers to create custom drinks. In addition, I added a MongoDB backend to store the custom drinks and display previously ordered drinks on the home page for others to see someone else's drink and add it to their cart. I use Prisma for the schema of the db. All of this works perfectly on my local machine. Once I deploy though, I get a 404 when trying to use any of my app.get commands. I put in a test get which is failing as well. I have been working with chatGPT to get me some answers but have no uncovered the issue still.

Here is some of my code

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import {} from 'dotenv/config'
import './config/database.js'
import path from 'path'
import logger from 'morgan'
import favicon from 'favicon'
import cors from 'cors'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'


const app = express()
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());



const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;


app.use(cors());


app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
  res.send('Test route works!');
});



app.get('/orders', async function(req, res) {
  const orders = await prisma.order.findMany({
    take: 20,
    orderBy: {
      createdAt: 'desc'
    }
  });
  res.status(200).send(orders);
});

app.post('/orders', async function(req, res) {
  
  const title = req.body.name;
  const glass = req.body.glass;
  const spirits = [];
  req.body.spirits.forEach(spirit => {
    spirits.push(spirit);
  });
  const mixers = [];
  req.body.mixers.forEach(mixer => {
    mixers.push(mixer);
  });
  const garnishes = req.body.garnishes;
  const price = req.body.price;

  console.log(title, glass, spirits, mixers, garnishes, price);


  const order = await prisma.order.create({
    data: {
      title: title,
      glass: glass,
      spirits: spirits,
      mixers: mixers,
      garnishes: garnishes,
      price: price
    }
  });

  res.status(200).send(order);
});




// The following "catch all" route (note the *) is necessary
// to return the index.html on all non-AJAX/API requests
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


app.listen(3001, () => console.log("listening on port 3001"))
```

Snippit of my Home.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Home( { cartItems, setCartItems } ) {
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Environment API URL: " + process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL); // Log the API URL based on environment
    
        async function getOrders() {
            // Use environment variable for API URL
            const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/orders";
            const result = await axios.get(apiUrl);
            setOrders(result.data);
        }
        getOrders();
    }, []);
```

I am using .env.local for my local var and have uploaded the correct (I think) variables to Heroku Config Vars

When browsing to https://pickyour-poison-d276c8edc8c1.herokuapp.com/test, I get No routes matched location "/test" and the "Test route works" does not display.

Checking the network tab, I see I get the following 304

```
Request URL:
https://pickyour-poison-d276c8edc8c1.herokuapp.com/test
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
304 Not Modified
Remote Address:
54.165.58.209:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

When Curl-ing https://pickyour-poison-d276c8edc8c1.herokuapp.com/test, I get

```
curl -v https://pickyour-poison-d276c8edc8c1.herokuapp.com/test
*   Trying 54.159.116.102:443...
* Connected to pickyour-poison-d276c8edc8c1.herokuapp.com (54.159.116.102) port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: pickyour-poison-d276c8edc8c1.herokuapp.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Cowboy
< Report-To: {"group":"heroku-nel","max_age":3600,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://nel.heroku.com/reports?ts=1709835610&sid=1b10b0ff-8a76-4548-befa-353fc6c6c045&s=lzyA9qH3L66E1VCtt2j8L4qz60aSKanwb%2BfWANWc%2Fsk%3D"}]}
< Reporting-Endpoints: heroku-nel=https://nel.heroku.com/reports?ts=1709835610&sid=1b10b0ff-8a76-4548-befa-353fc6c6c045&s=lzyA9qH3L66E1VCtt2j8L4qz60aSKanwb%2BfWANWc%2Fsk%3D
< Nel: {"report_to":"heroku-nel","max_age":3600,"success_fraction":0.005,"failure_fraction":0.05,"response_headers":["Via"]}
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 1711
< Etag: W/"6af-+M4OSPFNZpwKBdFEydrj+1+V5xo"
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2024 18:20:10 GMT
< Via: 1.1 vegur
```